# Original SCI-FI movie where an innkeeper has gills

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a movie on the original SCI-FI channel about a male and female protagonist stranded on an island village and while searching for answers the female protagonist notices an inn keeper had gill slits behind his ears. I can't remember the name of the movie.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you watch this film?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be the 2001 Spanish film, *[Dagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagon_(film))*:

> Paul Marsh has a dream that he discovers a mermaid with razor-sharp teeth while scuba diving into a strange underwater building. Paul awakes on a boat off the shores of Spain, where he is vacationing with his girlfriend, Barbara, and their friends Vicki and Howard. A sudden storm blows their boat against some hidden rocks. Vicki is trapped below deck and Howard stays with her while Paul and Barbara take a lifeboat to the nearby deserted fishing village of Imboca. During their absence, an unseen creature from the deep attacks the two in the boat.
>
> On the shore, Barbara and Paul find no one about and venture into town until they eventually reach the church, where they find a priest. Barbara convinces him to help them, and the priest speaks with two fishermen at the docks, who volunteer to take either Paul or Barbara to the wreck. Despite Paul's misgivings, Barbara stays to try to find a phone in order to call the police and a doctor while Paul goes to help their friends....

As per [this review](https://vocal.media/horror/reed-alexander-s-horror-review-of-dagon-2001):

> So you're telling me that the fish gills on the innkeeper's neck didn't give the characters any clue that there was something SERIOUSLY wrong? Okay. I mean, yeah the rest of the townsfolk looked fucking weird, but the innkeeper had fucking gills! That's sorta hard to overlook and one of those things you feel should have fucking come up.

I previously provided this film as an answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/237371/23243), so I suspected the film might include an innkeeper with gills, so I did a search for `dagon innkeeper gills` to find the review that mentioned it.

### Trailer

Comment: If this is correct, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/237370/23243 except that it's unaccepted.

Comment: After watching clips I think that Dagon is the title. Thanks for the helps guys.