# Need help finding movie or show (not anime) about a tentacle girl

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie or show can't remember few years ago. It's not an anime or animation pretty sure.

I dont remember much but I remember a scene.

The girl had tentacle legs? And she and this guy was running from her dad most likely and they hide in this dark room. She reveals her tentacle legs and they probably ended up in bed together. They run away and she goes in the water to save him I think but she ends up getting shot.

If anybody knows please answer and thank you!
This has been on my mind and I just really want to watch it again to stop thinking about it and relieve my brain.

Comment: “She reveals her tentacle legs and they probably ended up in bed together” — tale as old as time...

Comment: Your question has been marked a Duplicate. That's not a censure on you, just part of our bookkeeping that we've had this question before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be the 2001 Spanish film, *[Dagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagon_(film))*?

> Paul Marsh has a dream that he discovers a mermaid with razor-sharp teeth while scuba diving into a strange underwater building. Paul awakes on a boat off the shores of Spain, where he is vacationing with his girlfriend, Barbara, and their friends Vicki and Howard. A sudden storm blows their boat against some hidden rocks. Vicki is trapped below deck and Howard stays with her while Paul and Barbara take a lifeboat to the nearby deserted fishing village of Imboca. During their absence, an unseen creature from the deep attacks the two in the boat.

....

> Paul begs Ezequiel to help him escape. Ezequiel relents and takes Paul to the Mayor's manor, so he can steal the town's only car. Ezequiel distracts some Imbocans long enough for Paul to slip inside, but he accidentally honks the horn while trying to hot-wire the engine. Forced to flee into the manor, Paul finds a beautiful woman named Uxia, the mermaid from his dreams. She saves him from discovery, but when he finds that she really is half-fish, he flees in horror, despite her pleas for him to stay.

[This "5 Minute Movie" clip](https://youtu.be/iazcUxNOf8c?t=206) shows the reveal of her legs

[image: Image of Uxia with tentacle legs]

I happen to have provided this as an answer before.

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243840/original-sci-fi-movie-where-an-innkeeper-has-gills?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: THANK YOU! I can finally go on without thinking about the movie. This movie felt like a fever dream so I didnt even know if it was real. Thank you again and have a good day!

Answer (score 3):

Honorable mention for the much more recent live action 2014 film [*Spring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_(2014_film)), which features vacation romance, bedding, body horror reveals, and, yes tentacles (no scuba, though). Here's the movie poster:

[image: Movie poster for the 2014 film Spring]