Movie identification 90s-ish on the Syfy channel sea creature
I remember clips from a movie I saw on the Syfy channel as a kid. Could have been a 90s film or older. Here's what I remember:

There was a woman who was some sort of sea creature/had tentacles
There was a gorey scene with a big pit and someone hanging over it in chains all whipped up. i think there was a monster that would eat anything that fell into the pit
At the end there was a guy who got dragged into sea by this mermaid creature thing, I think he was dying?
I definitely remember a weird line spoken by a female non-human character that was something like "you are my brother and you are my lover" I remember it cuz it was weird.

What was this movie I've always wanted to watch it again!

The year 2001 saw a remake of the old sci-fi film "The She Creature" that used a mermaid, also the film "Dagon", with a woman having tentacle legs.

It's definitely not She Creature or Deep Rising because I watched those recently....Dagon is looking pretty likely, thank you!

Is this Dagon (2001)...?

A boating accident runs a young man and woman ashore in a decrepit Spanish fishing town which they discover is in the grips of an ancient sea god and its monstrous half human offspring.

Two married couples are vacationing on a boat off the coast of Spain when the boat gets stuck on a rock, trapping one of the passengers on board. One of the couples, Paul and Barbara, use a rubber dinghy to reach a nearby fishing town to look for help.
Regarding the specific plot points described in the question:

Paul encounters a woman who appears human initially, but is revealed to have tentacles instead of legs and gills on her torso.
Barbara is captured, stripped naked and suspended over a watery pit with cuts all over her body as a sacrifice to Dagon, a sea monster worshipped as a god.
Paul sets himself alight and is dragged into the pit and underwater by the woman with tentacles for legs.
Just before this, the woman speaks the line:


You are my brother. You will be my lover... forever.





This film has some striking similarities to Resident Evil 4. So much so, that I suspect it served as one of the main inspirations for the setting and some of the characters in that game.

Anyone in the US (or anyone with a VPN) can currently watch this film for free on Tubi.

If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243840/original-sci-fi-movie-where-an-innkeeper-has-gills/243842#243842 (from which you can see that this has shown up a number of times).
